# C# change color of textbox lines using a string builder

Tags: c#, networking

I'm implementing a ping test that will see if remote computers are online or not. I have a text box where you put the computers IP in and then a button that when pressed, pings all the computers to see if they are online. I would like to change the color of the line to reflect online or offline ( green or red ). My current code changes the entire textbox color to red if one fails.

My goal is if one of the computers fails the ping test, it would show up as red while the others would stay green if they receive a ping back.

Thanks.

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var line in txtcomputers.Lines)
    {
        string strhost = line;
        if (strhost.Length > 0)
        {
            Ping pingSender = new Ping();
            PingOptions options = new PingOptions();
            options.DontFragment = true;
            // Create a buffer of 32 bytes of data to be transmitted.  
            string data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
            int timeout = 120;
            try
            {
                PingReply reply = pingSender.Send(strhost, timeout, buffer, options);
                if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                    txtcomputers.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                else
                    txtcomputers.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In using a RichTextBox as Jon suggested you will need to use [`SelectionStart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.selectionstart.aspx), [`SelectionLength`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectionlength%28v=vs.100%29), [`SelectionColor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectioncolor%28v=vs.100%29) and [`GetFirstCharIndexFromLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.getfirstcharindexfromline%28v=vs.100%29) to get the starting character index of each of your lines.  See if this will work for you.

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    Color originalColor = txtcomputers.SelectionColor; ;

    for (int i = 0; i < txtcomputers.Lines.Count(); i++)
    {
        var line = txtcomputers.Lines[i];
        string strhost = line;
        if (strhost.Length > 0)
        {
            Ping pingSender = new Ping();
            PingOptions options = new PingOptions();
            options.DontFragment = true;
            // Create a buffer of 32 bytes of data to be transmitted.   
            string data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
            int timeout = 120;
            try
            {
                PingReply reply = pingSender.Send(strhost, timeout, buffer, options);
                txtcomputers.SelectionStart = txtcomputers.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(i);
                txtcomputers.SelectionLength = strhost.Length;

                if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                {
                    txtcomputers.SelectionColor = Color.Green;
                }
                else
                {
                    txtcomputers.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
                }


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            txtcomputers.SelectionLength = 0;
        }
    }
    txtcomputers.SelectionColor = originalColor;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that a `TextBox` can't have multiple colours of text in it. (At least in Windows Forms. You haven't specified what platform your GUI is using.)

You should look at [`RichTextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx) instead, which definitely *does* allow for that.

Comment: ah that would explain it. How would i go about doing it in a rich text box ?

Comment: @Boundinashes6: Follow the documentation link and I suspect you'll find enough information there :)